# Can we use a select query in alter table command in db2 database

Tags: db2

I have a foreign key constraint on my table created using the following command in db2

```
ALTER TABLE "ADDRESS" ADD FOREIGN KEY("CITY_ID") REFERENCES CITY("ID");
```

Now I am trying to drop the constraint. Since there was no name given to the constraint while creating, the alter command to drop the foreign key does not work.

Can I use a select command inside the alter table command so that I can query the `SYSCAT.TABCONST` table to get the constraint id?

Something like

```
ALTER TABLE ADDRESS DROP FOREIGN KEY 
  (SELECT CONSTNAME FROM SYSCAT.TABCONST where tabname='ADDRESS' and TYPE='F')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (SELECT 'ALTER TABLE '||TABSCHEMA||'.'||TABNAME||' DROP CONSTRAINT '||CONSTNAME FROM SYSCAT.REFERENCES WHERE TABSCHEMA=USER AND TABNAME='ADDRESS' AND REFTABSCHEMA=USER AND REFTABNAME='CITY');
END@
```

Note that there may be multiple ADDRESS -> CITY references. But this will work if there is only one such a foreign key between these tables.
We assume here that both tables are in the current user's schema.

Answer (score 0):

You can use compound SQL for this. Here is an example:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
begin
    declare v_fkname varchar(128) default '';
    declare v_sql varchar(1024);
    declare v_not_found integer default 0;
    declare not_found condition for sqlstate '02000';
    declare continue handler for not_found set v_not_found=1 ;
    set v_fkname = (select constname from syscat.tabconst where tabname='ACTORS' and tabschema='USER1' and type='F');
    if v_not_found = 0
    then
        set v_sql='ALTER TABLE actors DROP FOREIGN KEY '||v_fkname ;
        execute immediate(v_sql);
    end if;
end@
```

Remember that you will also need to [verify](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0053626.html) afterwards that no objects have become invalid as a result of this change.